# Фреймворк для браузерной игры

Tags: framework, php, разработка-игр

Сейчас один достаточно компетентный человек сказал мне, что браузерную игру лучше всего делать без фреймворка, т.к. тогда достигается наибольшая скорость, а фреймворки (даже самые быстрые) тянут с собой слишком много для таких проектов, в т.ч. роутинг тратит слишком много ресурсов. Подскажите, стоит ли делать браузерку на основе фреймворка (я присмотрел CodeIgniter), или лучше с нуля?

Comment: Не разбираюсь в браузерных технологиях, поэтому оформляю как коммент. Мне кажется, ответ на этот вопрос больше всего зависит от вашего опыта в разработке, чем особенностей технологий. Если это первый такой проект, делайте как вам проще, не надо гоняться за мифической оптимизацией :)

Comment: Да, первый.

Comment: Эм.. А как вооюще роутинг связан с игрой?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если есть время, напишите с нуля. Получите опыт и на ошибках поймете что и как. А потом уже можно и на фреймворке.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже начала некоторое время назад с нуля, потом подумал о большем качестве при использовании фреймворка, и сейчас начал с фреймворком CodeIgniter, но почти ещё ничего не сделал.
Думаю. Наверно, вернусь к старому.

Comment: @Construct верное буде решение!

Answer (score 7):

Если выбирать фреймворк для игры посмотри на эти:

[Crafty](http://craftyjs.com/)

Легкий модульный игровой движок, включающий множество функций: анимацию, управление событиями, перерисовку регионов, отслеживание пересечений и столкновений, спрайтовую графику и многое другое. Поддерживает все браузеры, в т.ч. IE9. Никаких дополнительных усилий прилагать не требуется.

[Quintus](http://html5quintus.com/)

Quintus – игровой HTML5-движок, разработанный, чтобы быть модульным и легковесным, с четким JavaScript-подобным интерфейсом. Для того, чтобы реализовать основные особенности ООП-игрового движка в HTML5-движке, в Quintus в некотором отношении схож с jQuery, а также поддерживает плагины, управление событиями и гибкую модель наследования, чтобы упростить повторное использование реализованных функций.

[gameQuery](http://gamequeryjs.com/)

Простой в использовании плагин jQuery, упрощающий разработку игры за счет использования реализованных игровых компонентов. Благодаря особенностям реализации совместим со множеством браузеров, в т.ч. их мобильными версиями.

[GMP](http://gogomakeplay.com/)

Идеально подойдет для реализации 2D спрайтовых аркад в ретро-стиле и головоломок вроде Судоку. Он имеет готовый к использованию самозапускающийся игровой цикл. Поддерживаются мышь и клавиатура. Отлично документирован, и главным недостатком можно считать только отсутствие поддержки звуков.

[lycheeJS](https://lychee.js.org/#!vision)

Игровая библиотека JavaScript, которая предлагает готовое решение для проектирования и реализации HTML5 Canvas и WebGL или нативных OpenGL игр внутри браузера или стационарных платформ. Оптимизирован для Google Chrome.

[Enchant.js](http://enchantjs.com/)

Фреймворк Enchant.js для HTML5+JavaScript игр был разработан в 2011 году, распространяется с открытым исходным кодом (MIT лицензия) и потому бесплатен.

[The Render Engine](https://github.com/bfattori/TheRenderEngine)

Кросс-браузерный опенсорсный движок, написанный полностью на JavаScript. Созданный с нуля для того, чтобы быть максимально гибким, он имеет обширный API и использует самые новые фичи современных браузеров. Этот фреймворк предназначен, чтобы делать все за вас: ваша идея – его реализация с помощью самых часто используемых инструментов.

[GameJS](http://gamejs.org/)

Большая библиотека на верхнем уровне HTML Canvas. В добавок к функциям рисования в ней имеется растущий ассортимент полезных для разработки игр модулей. Большинство имеющегося API основан на популярной PyGame.

CSS Game Engine

Для формирования страницы используются JavaScript и CSS. Вместе они работают достаточно уверенно и слаженно. Разработан для новичков, обучающихся азам программирования видеоигр. Вам будет проще, если у вас уже есть какие-то навыки работы с CSS.

[ClanFX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clanfx/)

clanfx основан на JavaScript и CSS и использует плиточную графику. Работает на данный момент в Firefox, Epiphany и Opera. Среди реализованных фич: анимированные спрайты, эффекты заклинаний, постройки, плитки/текстуры и базовый искусственный интеллект.

[gTile](http://game.tyler-dewitt.com/)

Браузерный движок на чистом JavaScript и DHTML. В gTile плиточная графика была выбрана за ее простоту и доступность. Упор в реализации был сделан на высокий уровень интерактивности и поведении игровых объектов. Меньшее внимание было уделено графике. А потому движок подойдет больше для создания текстовых РПГ, а графических возможностей должно хватить для изображения локаций.

[J5g3](http://j5g3.com/)

Графический JS движок с открытым исходным кодом (GPLv3). Легкий в использовании синтаксис предназначен для того, чтобы сделать фреймворк быстрым и расширяемым.

[Jaws](http://jawsjs.com/)

2D игровая библиотека, основанная на HTML5. Использует и Canvas, и средства DOM.

[Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d.org/)

Портированный с iPhone графический 2D HTML5-движок на JavaScript. Позволяет быстро создавать 2D игры и графические приложения, которые могут работать на всех современных устройствах без установки дополнительных плагинов.

[CopperLicht](http://www.ambiera.com/copperlicht/)

WebGL библиотека и JavaScript 3D движок для создания браузерных игр и 3D приложений. Использует WebGL Canvas, поддерживаемый современными браузерами и способный поддерживать рендеринг 3D моделей, используя аппаратное ускорение без плагинов.

[Aves](http://www.wonderlandblog.com/wonderland/2010/04/aves-an-html-javascript-game-engine.html)

Этот HTML/JavaScript движок – реинкарнация набора инструментов для разработки олдскульных RPG (но с более привлекательной графикой). И все только с помощью HTML и JS. Никаких плагинов. Никакого Flash.

[LimeJS](http://www.limejs.com/)

HTML5 движок для разработки игр с поддержкой сенсорного ввода. LimeJS создан с использованием Closure Library, созданной Google, и в нем уже реализованы классы и функции для отслеживания времени, событий, обработки форм и анимации. Также фреймворк поддерживает спрайтовые листы (т.е. все используемые изображения могут быть помещены в один файл).

[Phaser](http://phaser.io/)

Ещё один фреймворк для создания мобильных и десктопных игр на HTML5 с применением Canvas и WebGL. Бесплатный и с открытым исходным кодом. Есть быстрые гайды для старта на JavaScript и TypeScript.

Comment: здесь ссылка на отличные уроки по созданию игр. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543234/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C/

Answer (score 0):

Страдал аналогичным, фреймворки сам не люблю, да они тянут слишком много и ресурсы жрут от 5-100 раз. Но в чистый js, css3, вьезжать будет дольше. НО эффективнее намного и гибче! Опять НО, если цель единична, игра, то это не профи область для разработчиков, то есть смысл юзать фреймворки! Ибо зачем оптимизация в браузерной игре?! Эти области это всегда первые шаги и учеба, саморазвитие!

Comment: Вот как раз в играх то оптимизациям и самое место.