# Что начать изучать?

Tags: html5, разработка-игр, веб-программирование

Хочу сделать веб карточную онлайн игру,  не знаю с чего начать изучать? Никакого опыта созданий ни веб, ни игр нет...  Может подскажите какой движек выбрать и тд... Много материала про юнити,  но я думаю это не то для карточной игры,  а что то,  я не знаю. И на html5 можно игру сделать?

Comment: Может http://phaser.io/ подойдет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую начать изучение с создания игры на чистом js . Наберёшь немного опыта, будешь понимать как всё работает - без проблем выберешь движок для себя.

В помощь плейлист уроков по созданию игры на чистом js:

[Создание игр на JavaScript. Основы](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLf0k8CBUad-sHxpoBHLHIr3CwWfSmOYZR)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в этой ветке я собрал некоторые игровые движки, на которые стоит обратить внимание при выборе фреймворка для разработки игры. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/74679/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B/