# Разработка игр для браузера. Аналог игры "Age of empires 2"

Tags: javascript, html5, unity3d, разработка-игр, flash

Не могу разобраться в вопросе имются ли технологии позволяющие написать аналог 2D игры "Age of empires 2" для браузера? (Строительство зданий в любом подходящем месте, добыча ресурсов, заказ войск, усправление войсками, сражения и т.д.)
На каких технологиях имеется возможность создать такую игру? Насколько понял технологий html5 + javascript + css не позволят это сделать. Все что находил - весьма примитивное.

Насколько понимаю, Flash-игры подойдут для реализации такой игры?

Также, в Unity есть возможность экспорта игры для работы в браузере, но пока не смог понять, какие будут ограничения для такой игры.

В общем, хотелось бы понять на чем такую игру лучше написать, чтобы на ней была возможность играть в браузере. Спасибо!

Comment: canvas/webgl + js вполне позволяют

Comment: Вот например http://www.feudalwars.net/

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Спасибо за комментарии!

Comment: посмотрите может сгодиться фреймворк - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/74679/Фреймворк-для-браузерной-игры/543554#543554

Comment: Кириллы проснулись?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотри в сторону специализированных библиотек, для разработки игр в вебе, такие как [Phaser](https://phaser.io/), на сайте есть куча примеров реализации разных игровых механик, а так же подробное описание, правда пока только на английском.

Answer (score 1):

Flash - уж точно не стоит использовать. Браузеры отказываются от него, Adode прекращает обновления. К 2020 году будет полностью отключен https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=46916

Будущее за HTML5, WebGL, Canvas!

Comment: Скажу больше, ребята из Adobe когда припекло быстро сообразили что к чему и Adobe Flash эволюционировал в [Adobe Animate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Animate). Все тоже самое по функциональности, но теперь работает под HTML5 Canvas и WebGL.

Answer (score 0):

Вам может помочь готовое решение в области мультиплеерных игр на одном из самых популярных игровых движков - [Unity3D](https://unity3d.com/ru][1]).
В нем имеется очень популярный ассет, позволяющий создавать мультиплеерные игры - [Photon](https://www.photonengine.com/en/PUN).

В прошлом мы выпустили игру именно на нём.